# hyperlink text in word 2010 document to another header

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I want to link text to another header, but I want the text that link that header to contain the number of the header.

For example:

```
4.2.5 Header of a section
... text ...


7.4.2 Header of another section
... text ... (**as seen in section 4.2.5**)
```

Now, I want the bold text to link to section 4.2.5, but I also want the text 4.2.5 to change to the correct number in case 4.2.5 changes.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is based on the assumption that you've already set up headings (e.g. Heading 1, Heading 2) that include numbering, so that the 4.2.5 in your example will get updated automatically, when you add or remove a section.

The feature you are looking for is called **Cross-reference**.

1. Position the cursor just after "*as seen in section*"
2. Select the **References** tab of the Ribbon
3. Click on **Cross-reference** in **Captions**

   This brings up the Cross-reference dialog:

   [image]
4. Be sure to change the Reference Type to **Heading**
5. In the list, click on the heading you want to link to
6. Set your other options, as desired, e.g. whether you want to **Insert a hyperlink** and - in **Insert reference to** - what text you want to be displayed, e.g. just the Heading number (which it sounds like you want), or something more detailed, e.g. "Heading text"
7. (Obviously) Click **Insert**

Other useful info:

- If any of the linked text changes, Select All, right-click on the document and select **Update Field**
- You can also Select All, right-click and say **Toggle Field Codes** to see the recipes that Word uses to create these links
- You can right click on an individual Field, and select **Edit Field...** - this brings up this really powerful dialog:

  [image]
- In File -> Options -> Display, you can tell Word to always **Update fields before printing**, to save you having to remember.

Comment: Word 2013 seems cannot do this ? Any solution for Word 2013 ?

Comment: Sorry, find it.  Word 2013 uses [ Numbered item ] instead of [ Heading ] in my document.

Comment: So much power in Word that goes relatively unused. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Word 2013 :

1. Select the INSERT tab of the Ribbon
2. Click on the Cross-Reference button in the Links Section
3. Select your section to link
4. Press Insert